# Extending the years on Pop Up Calendar in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, content-management-system, drupal-modules

I am working on a drupal 7 site where the popup calendar only goes to 2020.  I Need to extend it to at least 2025.  How do you change that widget to get more years to display?
[image]

Comment: Are you using this widget in a date field? If so, go to `admin/structure/types/manage/NODE_TYPE/fields/YOUR_FIELD` -> `More settings and values` -> `Date entry` -> `Ending year` and set `+8 years from now`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I tried that but it didn't change.  Is there another option?

Comment: It could be also a view. Maybe you have to change the settings there.

Comment: Oddly enough, that was the first thing I checked, but luck.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Huelfe.  What you suggested is right.  I looked at the calendar but the calendar ended in 2020 because that is the last event scheduled.  But, when I went into the content itself and created a new event, dates up to 2027 were available, so it does work.  Thank you.